# PHP substitute, "If $something = "0" then $something1 = "no""

Tags: php, html, arrays

So basically what am trying to achieve is the following.

I am trying to make it so the following script does something in this instance:

```
If $something == "0" then $something1 == "no"
If $something == "1" then $something1 == "yes"
else echo "Error."
```

That is how I would explain what Im trying to do.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['resolve'])){
    $api = "http://test.com/php/";
    if(strlen($_POST['name'])==0){
        echo "fill in all fields!";
    } else {
        $response = file_get_contents($api.$_POST['name']); 
        $array = unserialize($response);
        ?>
        <div align="center"><?php echo "".$array['something1']; ?></div>
        <?php
     }
}
?>
```

I would like it to echo "`no`" if the result of array "`something`" is "`0`" and echo "`yes`" if the result of array "`something`" is "`1`".

Comment: Try [`else if`](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.elseif.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['resolve'])) {
    $api = "http://test.com/php/";
    if(!$_POST['name']) {
        echo "Please, fill in all fields!";
    } else {
        $response = file_get_contents($api.$_POST['name']); 
        $array = unserialize($response);
        echo "<div align='center'>";
            if($array['something'] == '0') {
                echo 'No';
            }
            elseif($array['something'] == '1') {
                echo 'Yes';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error.';
            }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Don't forget to also do a security input check on $_POST['name']

Comment: What do you mean security input?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if($array['something'] == '0'){echo 'No';}
elseif($array['something'] == '1'){ echo 'Yes';}
else{ echo 'Error!'; }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`switch case` is the most elegant way to go here:

```
switch($array['something']) {
    case 0: echo 'No';break;
    case 1: echo 'Yes';break;
    default: echo 'Error.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Voila

```
echo $array['something1'] ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: This would echo Yes for any `value >= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This sets `$array['something1']` to either 'yes' or 'no' depending on the value of `$array['something']`.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['resolve'])){
    $api = "http://test.com/php/";
    if(strlen($_POST['name'])==0){
        echo "fill in all fields!";
    } else {
        $response = file_get_contents($api.$_POST['name']); 
        $array = unserialize($response);
        $array['something1'] = $array['something'] == 0 ? 'no' : 'yes';
        ?>
        <div align="center"><?php echo "".$array['something1']; ?></div>
        <?php
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yesno = ['No', 'Yes'];
$something1 = $yesno[$something];
```

That is the simplest way I know of doing it.